# Python printing timedelta calculation output

Tags: python, timedelta, calculation

I have the following python code to calculate how many days, hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds an amount of marsdays is. I want the output to be:

x sols = x days, x hours, x minutes, x seconds, x milliseconds

I found out I had to use timedelta because it uses milliseconds, which I need.

I have written the following code but it doesn't give a correct output for the values. When they're >60 they need to be passed on because 60 seconds equals 1 hour. But the values can go >60. for example, when I enter a value >1, like 4, I get the aswer: 4 sol =  4 days, 2 hours, 38 minutes, 7220 seconds, 976 milliseconds.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
sol = timedelta(hours=24,minutes=39,seconds=35,milliseconds=244)
amount = input("Amount of sols: ")
earth=int(amount)*sol
hours = int(earth.seconds/3600)
minutes = int((earth.seconds-(hours*3600))/60)
secondes = int(earth.seconds-(minutes*60))
millisecondes = int(earth.microseconds/1000)
print (amount + " sol = " + str(earth.days) + ' days, ' + str(hours) + ' hours, ' + str(minutes) + ' minutes, ' + str(secondes) + ' secondes, ' + str(millisecondes) + ' millisecondes')
```

The hours, minutes and milliseconds are calculated this way because timedelta can't give them apparently.

```
earth.days
earth.seconds
```

exist, but

```
earth.hours
earth.minutes
earth.milliseconds
```

don't exist. which I don't understand because I can give them values as seen on line 2.

I think the way I try to achieve what i want isn't correct.

Comment: Off-topic, but [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) might be useful to you.

Comment: Hint: You forgot a term when calculating `secondes`. I bet that your `secondes` is off by a multiple of 3600.

Comment: I don't think I have, when i enter 1 as input the values presented are correct. Just when I enter a value >1, like 4, I get the aswer: 4 sol =  4 days, 2 hours, 38 minutes, 7220 seconds, 976 milliseconds.

Comment: 7220 is off by 2\*3600. You forgot to subtract _something else_ when calculating `secondes`.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use "seconds" as a floating point number instead of the `datetime` library it will work better. The `datetime` library has a lot of assumptions around Earth dates and times that won't really be valid on Mars.

Comment: I don't think using timedelta alone will have such issues, but I agree that asker should reconsider using timedelta instead of a float.

Comment: Isn't he suggesting it the other way around? That I have to use timedelta as a floating point?

Comment: @Sjoerd1234 He suggests that you use a `float` to represent seconds instead of going through `timedelta`.

Comment: He is definitely suggesting using a `float` instead of a `timedelta`.